# Can std::exception_ptr copy constructor throw?

Tags: c++, c++17

It seems to me that standard allows `std::exception_ptr` to not use ref-counting (i.e. `std::exception_ptr` cctor can be making a copy of exception object it points to). Which would mean [following code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr) may never call `handle_eptr()` and exception can escape `main()` with related consequences:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
 
void handle_eptr(std::exception_ptr eptr) // passing by value is ok  <---- ARE YOU SURE?
{
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    } catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Caught exception \"" << e.what() << "\"\n";
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::exception_ptr eptr;
    try {
        std::string().at(1); // this generates an std::out_of_range
    } catch(...) {
        eptr = std::current_exception(); // capture
    }
    handle_eptr(eptr);
} // destructor for std::out_of_range called here, when the eptr is destructed
```

Am I correct?

Comment: "std::exception_ptr is a shared-ownership smart pointer" it doesn't seem to me that its copy constructor would throw, even if it doesn't use reference counting (e.g., if instead of reference counting it uses a circular list).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can std::exception_ptr copy constructor throw?

No.

Standard says (latest draft):

> [propagation]
>
> exception_­ptr meets the requirements of Cpp17NullablePointer
>
> [nullablepointer.requirements]
>
> No operation which is part of the Cpp17NullablePointer requirements shall exit via an exception.